# Dockerized Kakfa Consumer no messages received

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, consumer

I am trying to get communications going between a kafka producer in one docker container and a kafka consumer running in a different container on the same host.

For now both containers are running on the same server (my local dev machine) but the ultimate aim is to have dockerized consumers running on remote servers.

The issue is that I am not getting any message throughput from the consumer when it's running in it's own container on the same host.

I am expecting that the containerized consumer can receive and print messages from the producer.

I have proved the following...

- A consumer in the same container as the producer can receive the messages.
- A consumer (not containerized) outside of the producer's container, but on the same host, can also receive the messages
- I have also tried putting both containers on the same docker network, but still not seeing any consumer throughput.

My dockerized consumer appears to get created and runs but I'm seeing no messages on it, it is silent.

**Here's the docker compose entry for the producer and some other relevant service definitions**

```
  kafka:
    image: quay.io/debezium/kafka:2.3
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      NODE_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
  zookeeper:
    image: quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:2.3
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
  apicurio:
    image: apicurio/apicurio-registry-mem:2.4.1.Final
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  connect:
    image: quay.io/debezium/connect:2.3
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
      ENABLE_APICURIO_CONVERTERS: true
    links:
      - cdm-db
      - kafka
      - apicurio
    depends_on:
      - cdm-db
      - kafka
  cdm-db:
    image: debezium/postgres:13-alpine
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

**The docker compose service entry for the consumer app**

```
app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "python -u manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]
        volumes:
            - ./static:/srv/static
            - ./media:/srv/media
            - ./app:/srv/app
            - ./import/:/srv/import
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:${APP_PORT}:8000"
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db
            - mq
            - redis
        environment:
            PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
        restart: always
```

The consumer process

```
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer

#BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="kafka:29092"    <----This setting works when consumer runs in same container as producer
#BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="localhost:9092" <----This setting works for consumer on host but outside container
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="host.docker.internal:9092" <----This setting for consumer in different container than      
                                                   producer on host - consumer gets created but I'm getting no output

def main():
    print("Starting consumer", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)

    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=[BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS],
            )
    except Exception as error:
       print("Error creating KafkaConsumer", type(error).__name__, "-", error)
       return -1

    print("consumer created.")
    print(consumer.config)

    consumer.subscribe("dbserver1.public.geography_country")
    try:
        for msg in consumer:
            print("consuming")
            print(msg)
    except Exception as error:
        print("Error consuming", type(error).__name__, "-", error)

    print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the dockerized kafka consumer to work with the following change in the kafka docker compose service definition

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
```

changed to

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://host.docker.internal:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your docker compose files live, if they both in the same directory, then both will be created under the same network ([compose networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)), in this case, containers in both files can communicate with each others via the service name, if each file in a separate directory, then you need to define the network section explicitly in **both** docker compose files, try to add the below section, after that all containers can communicate via service name:

```
networks:
  kafka-network:
    external: true
```

To verify that you containers are in the same network

1. List all networks `docker network ls`
2. Pick your network name e.g. `kafka-network` then run `docker network inspect kafka-network`, you should see your containers under `"Containers"` section.